# using RFID reader in a asp site

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have create a web site and I need to read data which is created by rfid reader.
this device has some dll which can be use in windows application.
I want to know that is there any way to use those dll in my site in order that I read data from RFID reader? if not is there any way to use that device in web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading dll's on a clients machine is seen as big security risk and there is not really allowed. It is possible to use ActiveX controls (basically dll's compiled into cab files) which the user can then enable and download, this then will allow you to talk to the ActiveX control which talks to the dll's, which talks to the RFID.

I would rather suggest you use something like Silverlight with out of browser mode, which you can run on the client machine with elevated privilages, then you can talk to com object. 
A much better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET application is Server side *application* with specific security restrictions applied. 
So basically, as the question is very generic so my answer too: *you can do it*, **it's enough to be sure that your architecture fits yuor ASP.NET security/permission requirements**.

Cause I immagine DLL is kind of COM component where you *push* signals and *read* alphanumeric characters  specifying your RFID (passive or active) identifier.

Regards.